# Unable to successfully compile C# 6 code using updated MSBuild

Tags: c#, batch-file, compiler-errors, msbuild

I have VS 2015 installed, as well as the 2015 version of MSBuild.  The original build bat file worked before the C# 6 code was added (with things like interpolated strings), but now the compiler throws errors on the C# 6 code.

The errors I get look like this:

`Folder\ClassName.cs(123,45): error CS1056: Unexpected character '$' [C:\Path\ProjectName.csproj]
Folder\ClassName.cs(123,45): error CS1056: Unexpected character '+' [C:\Path\ProjectName.csproj]`

Here's the original path that the bat file used:

`%WinDir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild`

I updated the path to this, but still get the same errors (the quotes were necessary because of the spaces in the resulting path):

`"%programfiles(x86)%\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe"`

I also tried using a switch found in other SO answers that worked for other people, but they didn't help in my case.

`/v:4.0` had the same result.

`/v:14.0` required some additional meta project files that this solution doesn't have.

How can I successfully update my bat command to compile C# 6 code?

Comment: Those errors are not cmd.exe errors.  So it is not a batch-file problem as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Squashman The batch file itself is not the problem, but the path/command you see in the question is IN the batch file, so it's related and relative to the problem at hand.